# Find a way to compute the number gcd(3^168 −1, 3^140 −1) without using a calculator and compute this number actually.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

I know i have to use euclidean algorithm somehow, but i have no idea how to apply it in this task, have i try this algorithm with powers of 3?